# is there a modern react listener for database changes

Tags: reactjs, websocket, signalr

Is there a modern React listener library for database changes? We need to implement some kind of real time communication with DB and be able to propagate DB changes to our clients. I heard about SignalR (just for ASP.NET?) but it seems Websockects could be the tech to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to adapt your persistence layer, you can achieve automatic DB->Web synchronization with Firebase Realtime Database:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

It's not React-specific, but the technologies work fine together (used them together myself). The Javascript-client uses Websockets behind the scenes.

Comment: We need to establish this with our own local DB. We are not allowed to use cloud techs. Thx